# Boundaries in superconductors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

In quantum mechanics we have the famous example of a
[particle in a box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box). The finite size of the System leads to a quantization of the momentum of the particle due to the Formation of standing waves in the system.

In superconductors we have the example of Andreev reflections [PRB 25, 4515 (1982)](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.25.4515), but here is the momentum fixed by the energy

$$
\left(\hbar k\right)^{2} = \sqrt{2m}\sqrt{E^2 - \Delta^2}\text{.}
$$

Further an interface between normal and superconducting regime is necessary.

My question is now, is something similar possible in superconductors? So that the formation of standing waves in the superconductor due to the finite size leads to a momentum quantization or only processes like Andreev reflections are possible, where an interface is necessary?

Comment: Of course you will have quantisation of the momentum due to finite size effect. What is more puzzling is what is the thermodynamic limit required to get phase transition in a finite system. The momentum is always fixed by the energy in stationary problems. You can invert the equation locally and say that energy is fixed by the momentum as well. In solid it's call a band structure. I do not really see the link between finite size effect and Andreev reflection.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be quite close to describing *Andreev bound states*. Recall that Andreev reflection involves an electron (hole) incident on an NS junction resulting in a Cooper pair in the superconductor, and a hole (electron) being reflected from the interface. In an SNS junction with a sufficiently narrow normal layer, where this process can occur at either junction, this results in a discrete spectrum of entangled electron-hole pairs. Because the processes are phase coherent, it turns out that these states can carry a supercurrent through the normal layer. Here's Figs 1a and 1b from [Pillet *et al.*, Nat. Phys. **6**, 965–969 (2010)](http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v6/n12/full/nphys1811.html);

[image: Andreev reflection and discrete spectrum]

In a) they show a schematic of the two superconducting leads with a normal region (labelled **Nanostructure** here) between them. Successive reflections occur at the interfaces, resulting in the discrete sub gap spectrum shown in b).